# WSO2 CEP fire BPS over SOAP failed

Tags: soap, wso2, complex-event-processing, wso2-cep

I want to invoke a BPS process from CEP through SOAP method, but got an exception in BPS side.

the event output formatter such as:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <eventFormatter name="output_formatter" statistics="disable"
     trace="enable" xmlns="http://wso2.org/carbon/eventformatter">
 <from streamName="output" version="1.0.0"/>
  <mapping customMapping="enable" type="xml">
  <inline>
  <TestEchoRequest>
    <input>{{meta_output}}</input>
  </TestEchoRequest>
</inline>
</mapping>
<to eventAdaptorName="outputadapter" eventAdaptorType="soap">
<property name="headers">SOAPAction:"http://wso2.org/bps/sample/process" </property>
<property name="username">admin@carbon.super</property>
<property name="password">admin</property>
<property name="url">http://192.168.20.213:9767/services/TestEcho/</property>
</to>
</eventFormatter>
```

but from the view of Enter Event Formatter Details, the headers property was mismatch to the XML version, lost the bottom half of "SOAPAction".

if fire the event from Event Stream Simulator, the BPS got an exception:

```
TID[-1234] [BPS] [2015-08-27 09:51:08,064] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine} - The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is http://192.168.11.250:9767/services/TestEcho/ and the WSA Action = . If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.
```

the message sent by CEP is just like this, it seems that the SOAPAction header is lost:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: ""
User-Agent: Axis2
Host: 192.168.20.213:9767
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

400
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Header><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1"><wsu:Timestamp xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="Timestamp-71"><wsu:Created>2015-08-28T05:14:09.554Z</wsu:Created><wsu:Expires>2015-08-28T05:19:09.554Z</wsu:Expires></wsu:Timestamp><wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="UsernameToken-72"><wsse:Username>admin</wsse:Username><wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">admin</wsse:Password></wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><event xmlns="http://wso2.org/carbon/event"><metaData><im>AAAAAAA</im></metaData></event></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
0
```

Is it a bug or any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

Above is a known issue in WSO2 CEP 3.1.0, see [1].. As a workaround can you call the soap12 endpoint of TestEcho service because SOAPAction property is optional in soap12 (Add complete url with soap12 endpoint for url property)..

example,
http://192.168.20.213:9767/services/TestEcho.TestEchoHttpsSoap12Endpoint/

[1] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CEP-1108